# Understanding English deeply like native speakers

Tags: language-acquisition, psycholinguistics

As I have noticed, a native speaker can actually judge the essence of person, the way he's feeling, even his personality through his writing or voice. Will it be possible for a non-native English speaker to understand English deeply like a native speaker? Most of the time it could be just hard to interpret the language for non-native speakers as their  native language.

Comment: Why is this tagged `language-acquisition`? It's not about acquiring a language.

Comment: Do you think this ability could be measured somehow?

Comment: I also suggest that you replace "essence", "feeling" and "personality" by more objective terms.

Comment: ***Some*** native speakers can do that, true; but, trust me -- many, perhaps most of them, **can't.** People vary immensely in their empathetic abilities. If you can do it in your native language, you can learn to do it in any language, but it takes a lot of time and continuous observation and practice. If you can't do it, forget about it; it's not one of your talents.

Comment: I don't know if it could be measured. I think I would accept @jlawler comment as an answer (of course, unless he decides to post it as answer) If there's no theory behind this.

Comment: I'd like to see more elaboration on that, though. @jlawler I suppose what you said is based on something you know/studied/seen?

Comment: More or less. I was a university professor of linguistics for 37 years, and met many people speaking and learning many languages. Some of them could do it, and some of them couldn't. People vary. A ***lot***.